# How update only one div's content in Yii by ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

I have a little problem about, when I try to update (refresh) my div's content, the Ajax replace the all page in that div.

Here the problem: [Screenshoot of the problem](http://postimg.org/image/6px3usp1z/)

Here is my controller source:[How should it looks](http://postimg.org/image/sww8tcsvl/76d84398/)

```
public function actionView() {
        //print_r($_POST);
        $model = null;

        if( "user" == Yii::app()->user->getState("user_type")){
            $model = new FormResultUser();
        }
        else if( "faction" == Yii::app()->user->getState("user_type")){
            $model = new FormResultFaction();
        }

        $index = 0;
        //echo $index;
        if( Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
            if(isset($_POST['index'])){
                $index = CPropertyValue::ensureInteger( $_POST['index'] ) +1;
            }
        }
        //echo $index;
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->limit = "1";
        $criteria->offset = $index;
        $questionModel = Question::model()->find($criteria);

       // print_r($questionModel);

        if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
            $this->render('_viewForm', array('model' => $model, 'questionModel'=> $questionModel, 'index'=>$index));
        } else {
            $this->render('viewForm', array('model' => $model, 'questionModel'=> $questionModel, 'index'=>$index));
        }       
    }
```

And my viewForm:
Here you can see, the AjaxSubmitButton is here. and `<div id="form">` is too, what I would like to update. ( and I would like to update the `$index` variable too in the ajaxSubmitButton)

I tired the '`replace'` too, but it doesn't work well, the problem is the same.

```
<?php /* FormFilling */ ?>
<div id="form">
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm'); ?>

    <?php
    $this->renderPartial('_viewForm', array('model' => $model, 'questionModel'=> $questionModel, 'index'=>$index, 'form'=>$form));
    ?>
    <div class="row margin10">

    <?php
    echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(Yii::t('strings', 'Next'), Yii::app()->createUrl('formFilling/view'), array(
            'type' => 'post',
            'data' => array("index" => $index),
            'update' => '#form',
        ));
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- end form -->
<?php
```

At finally my _viewForm:

```
<?php
$answers = CHtml::listData(Answer::model()->findAll(), 'value', 'label');
?>
<div id="formAnswer" class="row"></div>
<div class="row text">
    <p>
        <?php echo CHtml::encode($questionModel->text); ?>  
    </p>        
</div>
<div class="row margin10">
    <span>
        <?php echo CHtml::encode(Yii::t('strings', 'Answer options'), ''); ?>
    </span>
    <div class="margin10">
        <?php
        echo CHtml::activeRadioButtonList($model, 'answer_value', $answers, array("class" => "left"));
        ?>   
    </div>    
</div>
<div class="row margin10">
    <span>
        <?php echo CHtml::label(Yii::t('strings', 'Significant topic'), 'ch_answer_important'); ?>
    </span>

    <?php
        echo CHtml::activeCheckBox( $model,
                                    'answer_important',
                                    array("id" => "ch_answer_important", "class" => "left"));
    ?>   

</div>
<?php //echo CHtml::hiddenField('index', $index) ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to send only view template file in Yii, you need render view files by renderPartial(...) method of controller.

In this particular case you need change this code

> ...
>
> if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
>
> ```
>         $this->render('_viewForm', array('model' => $model, 'questionModel'=> $questionModel, 'index'=>$index));
> ```
>
> ..

to this

> ...
>
> if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
>
> ```
>         $this->renderPartial('_viewForm', array('model' => $model, 'questionModel'=> $questionModel, 'index'=>$index));
> ```
>
> ...

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following YII tutorial link to partial content update. Hence, you may update only <div> content.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/49/update-content-in-ajax-with-renderpartial